# PHP placement within HTML page?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have asked a question leading up to this earlier. Thanks again for your help.

- I have updated my .htaccess file in my root directory with the following:

  `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`
- Where within my .html page should I place the php tag?,

I still cannot seem to get my .html page to load the .php script.

Comment: You need to create `php` file and that should be run under apache server.

Comment: Do you have a server running?

Comment: what is the extention of ur page that u have created with the php code...

Comment: @Shomz - I'm somewhat a novice.  I use godaddy, but modified my .htaccess according to this guide that someone else provided for me: http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm

Comment: @dhpratik My website has all .html pages, and rather than updating everything to .php and breaking any existing links, it was suggested that I modify my .htaccess (like this link suggests http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm)  ... however, I have done so, but still cannot get the php to fire on my .html page, so I am assuming I am placing the tag in the wrong place?

Comment: Do you mind providing a live link of any page? Is your page extension .htm maybe?

Comment: @Shomz If you look at http://mudchallenger.com/index.php you will see the php fire when you move your mouse like you're leaving the website.  However, the same http://mudchallenger.com/index.html will not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean like leaving the website, you mean that popup is missing? If there's PHP on your HTML page, it's definitely rendered!

Comment: @Shomz - The .php version of the page renders perfectly, however the .html version of the page does not render the php.

The php script calls up a lightbox when your mouse breaks the browser plane, it's a last attempt to keep people on the site.

Comment: And what's your code to call and render that popup? I mean the original php code, not what's rendered as HTML.

Comment: @Shomz <?php include('exitpopup.php'); ?>

Comment: Hmmm, that looks fine, what happens if you change it to: `<?php require('exitpopup.php'); ?>`, does it load the page then?

Comment: @Shomz Unfortunately no. Nothing changed.

Comment: That is useful, you might want to edit your question and put that info there. One last shot from me: what happens if you leave only the `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html` in your .htaccess and remove everything else?

Comment: @Shomz Is it safe to do that?  I read elsewhere that could mess up other things?

Comment: Does it work like that? It's basically just telling the server to parse .html files as PHP.

Comment: @Shomz --- thanks for the info.  I called godaddy and I had modified the .htaccess file in the wrong folder and did not notice. Everything is good now.  Thank you!

www.mudchallenger.com/index-test2.html  ... seems to work, now to just build out some type of a submission form.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have followed this [guide](http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm) correctly, then according to the article, you should be able to execute php by simply opening a php tag.

From the article:

> ### Things to watch out for:
>
> - If you have an existing .htaccess file, add this to it, do not overwrite it or other >settings may stop working! Always be very careful with your .htaccess file and ask your >host if you need help
> - Anything in your .html files that starts with your file for some other reason (an XML tag for example) you will need to echo these lines >to prevent errors. For example:
>
> `<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="IUTF-8"?>'; ?>`

Comment: This is probably only valid if short tags are allowed.

Comment: As suggested, you can use the full php tag, because as in the example, he uses full php tags to echo out the xml. so I dont think this is only valid if if short tags are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Where within my .html page should I place the php tag?

The answer is you can place your php content anywhere in your html page as long as it is inside `<?php ?>` tag.

even if you have done correct modification to `.htaccess` file and still your php content is not getting parsed than check whether you are connected to server or not.